# Dificult scrapping with beautifulsoup4

Tags: web-scraping

I am doing a little script using python and beautifulsoup4, but I think the url I'm using is created dinamically or something similar.

My dubt is very simple, how can I get data (name, prize, shop, number of comments) of this product?

https://www.chollometro.com/ofertas/teclast-mini-pc-n20pro-16gb-512gb-1250828

Thanks

tried different soup.find_all span classes and not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting the HTML, I find it easier to parse it directly, rather than employing beautiful soup, using just [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) and `string.split()`.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.chollometro.com/ofertas/teclast-mini-pc-n20pro-16gb-512gb-1250828"
r = requests.get(url)

name = r.text.split("<title>")[1].split("</title>")[0]
print('name:', name)

price = r.text.split('"groups"')[1].split('"price":')[1].split(",")[0]
print('price:', price)

comments = r.text.split("commentCount")[1].split(":")[1].split(",")[0]
print('comments:', comments)


#name: TECLAST Mini PC N20Pro 16GB 512GB » Chollometro
#price: 139.19
#comments: 31
```

I don't get what you mean by `shop`. What is supposed to be the shop in this case?

Comment: thanks a lot, I will study because it works perfectly. Shop I mean where the product is bought (Amazon in this case)